# Use pager for output from Octave help command?

Tags: octave

Octave uses a pager for computational output, but not for the text outputfrom the help command.  This seems odd.  Is there a way to force Octave to use the pager for help?

I'm using an old cygwin version (corporate machine makes it hard to update):

```
GNU Octave Version 3.8.2
GNU Octave License: GNU General Public License
Operating System: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 2.0.2(0.287/5/3) 2015-05-08 17:00 x86_64
```

I also used the CLI by invoking octave using:

```
octave --no-window-system --silent
```

Comment: GNU Octave uses a pager per default. Are you sure you don't have something like "more off" in your .octaverc? And you really should mention the used version and if you use the CLI or GUI

Comment: Thanks for prompting me to add the requested details.  I didn't say that I have "more" turned on because the opening sentence already says that the pager is used for computational output  Plz let me know if this hasn't been clarified.